# breadcrumbs not working as expected

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

My menu looks like the following:

`defs` menu is linked to `def` view, `fghs` menu is linked to `fgh` view.

```
abcs | defs | fghs
```

Now when I click on `defs`, a view gets opened.
Now my breadcrumb is the following:

```
Home >> defs >> def
```

`def` is the view. In this view there is a link to *another view*. When I click on this view, the breadcrumb is the following:

```
Home >> fghs >> fgh
```

But I want the breadcrumb in this format:

```
Home >> defs >> def >> fgh
```

How can I achieve this? I am using **Bartik** theme.

In the `page.tpl.php` file, I am using the code below:

```php
<?php if ($breadcrumb): ?>
      <?php print $breadcrumb ?><?php if ($title != ""): ?><div class="breadcrumb">&raquo; <?php print $title ?></div><?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use **[Custom breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs)** module for defining overriding breadcrumbs: it supports [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token), which helps defining complex breadcrumbs (e.g. defining breadcrumbs from related taxonomy terms, etc.).

With this module, you can define custom breadcrumbs for the following entities: node, path, term, Views, vocabulary (on `admin/structure/custom_breadcrumbs`).
On `admin/config/user-interface/custom-breadcrumbs`, you can also set to append current page title by default too.

Its admin interface is really simple.

---

In your case, you should go to `admin/structure/custom_breadcrumbs/views/add`, set things like this (it's just an example):

[image: Add Custom breadcrumbs for Views]

Save, then go to `admin/config/user-interface/custom-breadcrumbs`, and check *"Append page title"*, hit "Save configuration", ready.

[image: Custom breadcrumbs - Append page title]

Answer (score 0):

[Hansel](http://drupal.org/project/hansel) module can do this quite easily.

> "Breadcrumbs done right"
>
> Hansel (named after Hansel and Gretel) provides custom breadcrumbs
>   which are build by user defined rules. These rules are independent
>   from the menu system. Rules can have logic switches and can add links
>   to the breadcrumbs.